# Not all MySQL processes are killed when restarting

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

We have a MySQL 5.6 server running on Ubuntu 12.04 using the [MySQL 5.6 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/mysql-5.6).

The service comes up fine when rebooting the box, but whenever we restart the MySQL process via `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`, some of the child processes are not killed, resulting in file lock errors when the daemon tries to start again:

```
2015-04-16 08:40:23 2713 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
2015-04-16 08:40:23 2713 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2015-04-16 08:40:24 2713 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
2015-04-16 08:40:24 2713 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2015-04-16 08:40:25 2713 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
2015-04-16 08:40:25 2713 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

Full config file:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
skip-external-locking
basedir                         = /usr
tmpdir                          = /tmp
pid-file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
lc-messages-dir                 = /usr/share/mysql
log-error                       = /var/log/mysql/mysql.err
user                            = mysql
port                            = 3306
bind-address                    = 192.168.50.253
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1

max_allowed_packet              = 1024M
thread_stack                    = 192K
thread_cache_size               = 32
query_cache_limit               = 128M
query_cache_size                = 32M
max_heap_table_size             = 512M
tmp_table_size                  = 2G
key_buffer_size                 = 1024M
sort_buffer_size                = 1024M
read_buffer_size                = 1024M
bulk_insert_buffer_size         = 1024M

myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 1024M
myisam_max_sort_file_size       = 20G
myisam-recover                  = BACKUP

innodb_thread_concurrency       = 8
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 5120M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 4
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_log_file_size            = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 8M
innodb_strict_mode              = 0
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        = 0

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 1024M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Is there anything anyone can see that could cause this behaviour? The `debian-sys-maint` user exists and has the appropriate grants.

Comment: Can you put check the PPID (Parent Process ID) of the mysql child process ? (Use `ps xao pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm`)

Comment: When grepped for 'mysql' that command returns: `1223     1  1223  1223 mysqld`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the issue for us was the use of the old-style `/etc/init.d/mysql` script, rather than the `service mysql restart` script provided by Upstart. We haven't had these issues when using the Upstart commands.